# Creating a graphical diagram of MYSQL tables

Tags: java, mysql, database, intellij-idea, mysql-workbench

I have a MYSQL schema with a large number of tables (more than 20).

Is it possible to somehow display a graphical diagram showing the relationships between tables and their fields?

I want to get something like a UML diagram (which is being built, for example, for Java classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's extremely easy to do in [Idea Ultimate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki9V5.png), and it's also possible in Workbench: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-eer-diagram-editor.html